# transform not synchronizing in the network(UNITY, unet)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to respawn a player after his health reaches zero
So I have a script on each player that changes the `transform.position` of the player to a vector3;

Problem is that even though on the other players the position does actually change to where I want it the player from his perspective stays in the same place and when other players got to his position or he decides to move he suddenly apears and continues from his position.
This is the part of the code that is executed once the player is shot and health is zero

```
    void destroy() {

    Debug.Log("i am dead");

    if (isClient) { transform.position = respawn2; }
    else { transform.position = respawn1; }

}
```

This code runs on the player object and the player does have network tranform.

Comment: We need to see more code than this. Is this an RPC function? What components are on the player object that are being synced?

Comment: @BenjaFriend this is not an RPC function nor command. It is just suposed to change the position of the player(who is an empty game object with some colliders and boxes as children). I thought there was no need for rpc functions and stuff because i already have the network transform component that should sync the position after the change. In terms of code i don't think there is much else to show

Comment: Did you try to add `if (! isLocalPlayer) return`? The thing is `isClient` is executed on all Clients. Your `else` is executed on the server.. is that your intention? You rather should only set the transformation on the localPlayer -> since it has localAuthority the transforme is than synced to the server and other clients